# Handle microsoft.sharepoint.dll version issue in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

In my application, I need to write the logs to SharePoint, as we know, in SharePoint 2010, it's easy to write the logs by using `WriteTrace()` and `WriteMethod()` methods, but in SharePoint 2007, we don't have the direct way to write logs, but I found the helpful article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979522%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

So here is the problem, as you know, the `WriteTrace()` and `WriteMethod()` methods are not recognised in SharePoint 2007, when we compile the code, it will throw the errors. But I don't want to separate the code into two parts, one for 2010 and the other for 2007. Any ideas for a good solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to separate the code. However, as a good design, you can refactor only the log tracing code into its own assembly and then load that assembly at the runtime using the `Factory` or `Abstract Factory` Design pattern.